# Knockout.js validation using extenders - prevent validation on load

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I have implemented a very basic required validation on "first name" largely based on the example suggested on knockout website (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) - Live example 2: Adding validation to an observable.

My problem is that I don't want the validation to fire when the form is first loaded. Below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<p data-bind="css: { error: firstName.hasError }">
    <span>First Name</span>
    <input data-bind='value: firstName, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
    <span data-bind='visible: firstName.hasError, text: firstName.validationMessage'></span>
</p>
<p>
    <span>Last Name</span>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: lastName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
</p>

<div data-bind="text: fullName" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.debug.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

var AppViewModel = function () {
var firstName = ko.observable().extend({ required: "Please enter First Name" }),
    lastName = ko.observable(),
    fullName = ko.computed(function () {
        return firstName() + " " + lastName();
    });
return {
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    fullName: fullName
};
};


ko.extenders.required = function (target, overrideMessage) {
//add some sub-observables to our observable
target.hasError = ko.observable();
target.validationMessage = ko.observable();

//define a function to do validation
function validate(newValue) {

    target.hasError($.trim(newValue) ? false : true);
    target.validationMessage($.trim(newValue) ? "" : overrideMessage || "This field is    required");
}

//initial validation
validate(target());

//validate whenever the value changes
target.subscribe(validate);

//return the original observable
return target;
};



var viewModel = new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

You will see the demo of issue I am facing at this link  [http://jsfiddle.net/tCP62/22/``](http://jsfiddle.net/tCP62/22/)

Please Note that the JSFiddle link that i have provided to demo showing the problem - works in "Chrome" and does not work in IE.

Please can anyone help me resolve this.

Regards,
Ankush

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get rid of the following line and it should do what you want:

```
//initial validation
validate(target());
```

The `required` extender gets called when your page loads, and because it contains the above call, it causes the validation to trigger immediately. The next line of code `target.subscribe(validate);` ensures that it is triggered when the observable changes value (as stated by the comment). And that's all you need in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much... I just couldn't see it in grand scheme of things... Spent around 4 hours yesterday and 4 hours toady before posting to stack overflow. But hey, you made my day. Thank you again.

Comment: Now I have another problem. I want to invoke the validation on save button click so that controls that have error get highlighted. Based on the above, I could invoke "validate" before save and check for "hasError" property. However what if I have two validations on "firstName" - say "required" as well as that firstName should start with "A" for which there is another extender. In this scenario, do I have to name the validate method differently on each extender and invoke all the validate methods for each observable that needs to be validated? Any help is very much appreciated.