# Knockout validation for select element appears on page load

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js

I'm having the exact same problem as [described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308684/knockout-validation-select-list-values). But the accepted solution does not solve the problem.

Here's my form element markup:

```
<select
    class="form-control"
    data-bind="options: industries, optionsText: 'description', optionsValue: 'code', optionsCaption: 'Choose...', value: industry_code"
></select>
```

My data looks like this:

```
[
    {"code":"00","description":"Unclassified","parent":null},
    {"code":"01","description":"Amusement\/Arcade","parent":null},
    ...
];
```

And I'm trying to make this field required with the following code:

```
self.industry_code.extend({
    required: { message: "Please select an industry." }
});
```

It works perfectly for selecting, updating, etc. but when I load the form for the first time, the "Please select an industry." message appears. None of my other knockout validation code (for `<input type='text'>` elements) does this, so I'd like this one to behave the same way.

I did try the solution mentioned in the question cited above (in fact, I was already using the `optionsCaption` binding). Maybe the I'm missing a step... [the answer to the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19309912/2008384) is vague to the point of being almost useless.

Has anyone else solved this problem?

Comment: Have you wrote `required` extender yourself? Maybe this solution would be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743462/knockout-js-validation-using-extenders-prevent-validation-on-load?

Comment: Similarly, if you are using the validation plugin's `group` function to trigger the validation, you'll want to make sure and not perform that call during page load. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/jztx7ctd/).

Comment: You haven't quite provided enough code to repro your scenario. Could you update the question with more code, perhaps backed by a fiddle? (If I imagine what your code *may* resemble [it works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/kgm8jhcs/1/): no error message on load.)

Comment: I would recommend you to use https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation You don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for your problem is quite easy. When you first initial your viewModel you need to call this instruction

```
self.Errors.showAllMessages(false)
```

This will disable all the errors on first load. Hope this helps.

Comment: Using this is perfect:
    ko.validation.group(yourViewModel, { deep: true }).showAllMessages(false);

............ However it must be done *after* calling applyBindings:

    ko.applyBindings(yourViewModel);

............ Otherwise it doesn't work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46597519/712700