# knockout dropdown validation on load? required

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js

There are many post on this one which i find not helpful and i need to find out why and how .

I made a fiddle with two controls dropdown and textbox and applied required validation with `.extend`  [My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/JL26Z/64/)

**Question 1 :**  when i first load my page i get a validation error beside dropdown but not beside textbox ? i am confused why is that .

**Question 2 :** Ok . its awkward to display a error message on load so i planned to disable error messages display on load . Added this line `ko.validation.init({ insertMessages: false });` . By this i got rid of on load error message display . BUT  when i click on submit i **can't** find the error message text beside textbox or dropdwon .

One way or the other dropdown is failing my cause to display error text.

Any feasible  approach is much appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you subscribe to your observables, you will see that `country` is actually set on load by ko, which is not the case for code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/67/)):

   ```
   self.Code.subscribe(function () { alert("Codes changed"); });
   self.country.subscribe(function () { alert("Country has changed"); });
   ```

   This is caused by how `select` is handled (how `options binding` is handled I believe) and explains why the validation is done on `country`.
2. `insertMessages: false` will hide all messages, then you need to handle them with the `validationMessage binding`.

Simply remove the init value of your observable ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/68/)):

```
self.Code = ko.observable();
self.country = ko.observable(); // no ""
```

Comment: ok gotcha . just because `""` its getting validated on load right .

Comment: i am still amused . why ? what the difference declaring `("")` and `()` .like  string vs any DT ?

Comment: I think when you write `()`, the observable gets `undefined` instead of an empty string. I guess there is a check on that in the `options binding`

Answer (score 2):

To disable messages on load you need this instruction

```
self.Errors.showAllMessages(false)
```

this will disable all message on first load. setting this will not help you

```
ko.validation.init({ insertMessages: false })
```

For your first problem, You must be doing this

```
<select data-bind='blah,validationElement:TextBoxField' >
```

this will cause it. Hope it helps.

Comment: tried `showAllMessages(false)` its not working as expected and also drop-down binding is getting empty .

Comment: stil i am looking for something best alternative .

Answer (score 1):

Using this is perfect:

```
ko.validation.group(yourViewModel, { deep: true }).showAllMessages(false);
```

However it must be done *after* calling applyBindings:

```
ko.applyBindings(yourViewModel);
```

Otherwise it doesn't work.